# How to write 4 colums in one row using Thymeleaf th:each

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem with rendering the Pageable response (***using Thymeleaf 2.0.19***) content to be displayed in rows of `<div class="span3">`. The row values are dynamic from Spring 3 MVC controller.

Below is the UI code i need to display product images in rows with each row containing 4 cols of span3.

UI snippet to display the product images in 4 cols per row.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid"  th:remove="all-but-first">
        <div th:each="asset,assetIter : ${page.content}" th:with="numList=${#strings.listSplit('3,2,1,0', ',')}" th:if="${assetIter.index}%4 == 0" class="span3">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <span><img src="../abc.png" /></span>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <p>Label1 : <span th:text="${asset.id}">Id</span></p>
                        <p>Label2: <span th:text="${asset.name}">Name</span></p>
                        <p>Label3: <span th:text="${asset.category}">Category</span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried one of the post responses from "Younghan Kim" posted at [in thymeleaf, how can write th:each to combine rows and columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812372/in-thymeleaf-how-can-write-theach-to-combine-rows-and-columns), however i need to display the values from within the page response object which is however String values in the response above.

So, how do i display the above code as rows with 4 cols. Please provide inputs and let me if i am missing out on something as i am new to thymeleaf impl.

Also the UI pagination is implemented on server side as mentioned in the blog below:
http://www.jiwhiz.com/post/2013/2/Implement_Bootstrap_Pagination_With_SpringData_And_Thymeleaf

Comment: "content to be displayed in rows of..."? Looks like you forgot to finish your sentence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It should have read "Content to be displayed in rows of 4 columns". And at the bottom of html snippet i was referring to one of the post responses provided by Youngham Kim on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812372/in-thymeleaf-how-can-write-theach-to-combine-rows-and-columns

Comment: You can edit your original question to include this extra information.