# How to iterate for X items in Thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have the template, where for four `li` elements I should have one `ul` element. How should I do this? Now I have something like:

```html
<div th:each="excursion,iterStat : ${excursions}">
    <ul th:if="${iterStat.index}/4 == 0">
        <li>
            <a th:href="@{/excursion/{id}(id=${excursion.excursionId})}"><img src="/template/images/garden1.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
            <h2 th:text="${excursion.title}"></h2>
            <p th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(excursion.description,128)}"></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I thought `if` condition will be applied to the elvery `ul` element, but it hide every thing, including `li` element.

Comment: So you want a brand new unordered list for every item instead of just a new row in list?

Comment: I need list with four elements. One way to achieve it is to make lists for every four elements. But I hope there is a way to do what I want with only one list.

Comment: If you need a list with 4 elements, what purpose does th:if="${iterStat.index}/4 == 0" serve? it will never work unless index = 0. If you want list with 4 elements, then just iterate 4 times. I'll add answer for you.

Comment: It seems the OP was really asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812372/in-thymeleaf-how-can-write-theach-to-combine-rows-and-columns.  However, if you are here (like me) because you wish to only show the top X items, the first accepted answer works except that, these days, you can't use < inside a th:if, so you must use lt instead.  Like this: th:if=${iterStat.index} lt 5"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per your comments, you needed a list with 4 items, the below will do the trick. Let me know if you got issues

```
<ul>
<div th:each="excursion,iterStat : ${excursions}" th:if="${iterStat.index}<5">    
        <li>
            <a th:href="@{/excursion/{id}(id=${excursion.excursionId})}"><img src="/template/images/garden1.jpg" alt="Image" /></a>
            <h2 th:text="${excursion.title}"></h2>
            <p th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(excursion.description,128)}"></p>
        </li>    
</div>
</ul>
```

EDIT 1:
Further review based on provided data yields another possibility.
Use Map instead of mass lists in Controller before you pass it:

```
Map<String, List<Excursion>> excursionsList;
```

Make sure you limit each excursion to 4 (as you require).
Then in Thymeleaf iterate through the map.

```
<div th:each="excursion,rowStat : *{excursionsList}">
<ul>
<div th:each="list,iterStat : *{excursion[__${rowStat.index}__].value}">
//your code for each list item information such as excursionId, description etc.
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

That should clean up your code heaps and make it as you need it.

Comment: I have more than 4 excursions (for example 5, or 10). And I want to split this list into ul lists with 4 elements each. Your code will display only first 4 records.

Comment: Ok i think you need to rewrite your question to clarify what you exactly after, it is very difficult to understand clearly. I am assuming that you are looking to implement some type of modulus so that every 4th iteration you create a new list? Is that correct?

Comment: Posted my answer. If you could rewrite it using only one list, I'll choose your answer.

Comment: I think i have a solution for you thats a lot simpler, simpler and more elegant. I'll write something up in morning for you.

Comment: @Dracontis did my second example help?

Comment: I don't understand why should I change to Map realisation from list of lists. I think it's okay to keep mine.

Comment: Personally it is to make cleaner more efficient code. It is also how I would solve the problem you are facing. The biggest advantage is for debugging purposes cleaner code makes this easier.

Comment: Note that "<5" isn't correct in the above answer.  You should use "lt 5" instead.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done to achieve what I want. Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping( "/" )
public String index( Model model ) {
    List<Excursion> excursions = excursionDao.findAll();
    List<List<Excursion>> excursionsLists = new LinkedList<List<Excursion>>();
    List<Excursion> tempList = new LinkedList<Excursion>();

    int listSize = excursions.size();
    for ( int i = 0; i < listSize; i++ ) {
        tempList.add( excursions.get( i ) );
        if ( listSize == ( i+1 ) || tempList.size() == 4 ) {
            excursionsLists.add( tempList );
            tempList = new LinkedList<Excursion>();
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute( "excursionsLists", excursionsLists );
    return "index";
}
```

And thymeleaf template:

```html
<ul th:each="excursionsList : ${excursionsLists}">
    <li th:each="excursion : ${excursionsList}">
        <a th:href="@{/excursion/{id}(id=${excursion.excursionId})}"><img src="/template/images/garden1.jpg" alt="Image"/></a>
        <h2 th:text="${excursion.title}"></h2>
        <p th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(excursion.description,128)}"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```