# how to iterate only x elements with thymeleaf?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have a list of X elements that I'm getting from the DB and I want to display only 10 rows

here is my code, now I display all the results

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="user :${users}">
            <td th:text="${user.getUserId()}" />
            <td th:text="${alert.getUserName()}" />
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

How can I do it without sending a shortest list? because I want to allow the client to download the full list as a csv file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate for X items in Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095444/how-to-iterate-for-x-items-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: For more info see [Iteration Status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#keeping-iteration-status).

Comment: @andrewJames no, I saw that question and he needed something else

Comment: Can you clarify? Does `th:if="${iterStat.index} < 5"` (or whatever value you need instead of 5) not meet your needs? How are you providing the full CSV details?

Comment: @andrewJames thanks! that answered my question, I am new with ```thymeleaf```